# Parent rigify part to empty

Tags: parent, rigify, empty

I'm working on an animation of a robot pedaling a bicycle. I have used rigify to
generate controls for the skeleton. I have added an empty to the rotating bicycle crank where the foot should contact it. What I'd like to do is parent the foot element to the empty, so that it will follow the rotation of the crank.

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, so what is your question? I guess you could use a Child Of constraint in order to parent the foot controller to the empty?

Comment: bingo!! Case closed!! many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Give a *Child Of* constraint to the foot controller bone with the empty as *Target*.